# How to print screen Visual Studio IDE including tooltip/intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, printscreen

Here is a printscreen of a tooltip/intellisense that is there before and after I hit the printscreen key.
[image]

Here is a an image from my camera.
[image]

Have also tried delayed printscreen with count down using 3rd party software.

How can i Printscreen including tooltips/intellisense?

Comment: @Red-Gate If someone made a plugin for this is would be ultra handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just fine with my keyboard. Maybe your print screen key is canceling the intellisense somehow.

Try using [Key Remapper](http://www.softarium.com/keyremapper/) to temporarily change you print-screen key and try again. It's the only thing that comes to my mind right now.

Comment: It was the 3rd party app I was using.